# Handling refresh tokens from Google via OAuth2

Tags: javascript, gmail-api

I'm struggling to figure out why my code will not handle refresh tokens when a user reauthenticates. Initial authentication works fine and I am able to receive the token and refresh tokens and save them to my database, but when a user comes back and needs to re-auth then my code hits a problem and throws an error when it hits the line where it tries to retrieve the unread emails.

```
Error being received is:
/app/node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:272
throw new Error('No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set.');
Error: No access, refresh token, API key or refresh handler callback is set.
```

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```js
    for (let user of users) {
        const email = user.email;
        let tokens = user.tokens;

        const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(process.env.G_CLIENT_ID, process.env.G_CLIENT_SECRET, process.env.G_REDIRECT_URL);

        if (oauth2Client.isTokenExpiring()) {
            const refreshedTokens = await oauth2Client.refreshAccessToken();
            oauth2Client.setCredentials(refreshedTokens.tokens);

            await usersCollection.updateOne({ email: email }, { $set: { tokens: refreshedTokens.tokens } }); // <-- Use the tokens property
        }

        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);

        const gmail = google.gmail({ version: 'v1', auth: oauth2Client });
        const response = await gmail.users.messages.list({
            userId: 'me',
            q: 'in:inbox is:unread',
        });
```